# Xamarin Forms Android Label displaying extra characters

Tags: text, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, newline

I am pulling text from an embedded .txt file and then displaying it in a label. iOS is fine, but Android shows extra characters. I am missing something simple but not sure what. Thanks for the help.

This (in a .txt file):

0.2.3
- Fixed spelling errors
- Added version number in slide-out menu
- Squashed bugs

0.2.2
- Database Change Log Added.
- Bug Fixes.

0.2.1
- Bug Fixes

Turns into this:

[image]

The space characters are bring shown. How do I prevent this?

Retrieving the text:

```
 var assembly = typeof(MainMenuViewModel).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
 Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("ReleaseNotes.txt");

 var text = "";
 using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
 {
     text = reader.ReadToEnd();
 }
 ReleseNotesText = text;
```

The Label:

```
<Label Text="{Binding ReleseNotesText}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TextColor="{DynamicResource TextColor}" FontSize="18" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More likely your newlines are `\n` in the embedded text file stream

Just convert them to the correct environment newline. Newline character(s) may vary depending on the running platform... in .NET you have the handy `Environment.NewLine`, thus:

```
ReleseNotesText = text.Replace("\n", Environment.NewLine);
```

**Edit:** after taking a look at the exact text file in the comments, it looks like it was using the U+2028 unicode sequence for newlines. The correct replacing code would be:

```
ReleseNotesText = text.Replace("\u2028", Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: This does not work. There is no visible new line character in the string. And strangely, altering the text in the .txt file to use "\n" in place of hitting enter to move to the next line, xamarin is escaping it so it ends up like this "\\n".

Comment: Can you upload the txt file somewhere (not copy & paste, but upload the exact file) so I can take a look at the characters?

Comment: Your text file contains the UTF-8 "E2-80-A8" sequence for newlines (unicode U+2028, or Line Separator)... that's usually not supported as a correct newline except in JavaScript (and iOS as it looks for your example)... *maybe it comes from a Javascript generated JSON?*. Use `text.Replace("\u2028", Environment.NewLine);` instead. I'll edit my answer

Comment: Perfect JCL, that worked. What editor are you using to see those characters? I tried VSCode, VSMac, all the native Mac editors, google docs, SublimeText and none of them show it.

Comment: I actually copied and pasted the text (using Notepad++, but any other editor should do) and made a small application in dotnetfiddle to see what that character was in hex (I also tested the solution, just in case): https://dotnetfiddle.net/7ihgI1 . In the dotnetfiddle editor it appears as a red dot (and it fails compilation unless I use the string as verbatim using `@` because it takes it as a newline too). Converted it to the UTF8 bytes and printed the hex values. This wouldn't work after being parsed, that's why I needed the txt file and couldn't copy from the stackoverflow question :-)